# Antimalware Service Executable

Tags: windows-xp, anti-malware

I have or had Windows XP. Now receiving a pop-up window at the beginning of start-up. What is Antimalware Service Executable? should I click on the "Send Error Report" box below in this window? Is it legitimate and from Microsoft? Is it unsafe and do I need to get rid of it and if so how do I do I get rid of it?

Thank You,
Susan

Answer (score 1):

The **Antimalware Service Executable** (`MsMpEng.exe`) is part of the [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) (MSE) engine. Assuming you have it installed, it might have crashed for some reason and now Windows asks you to send an error report. Although you don't have to, it's probably a legitimate dialog which should look like this:

[image: Microsoft Error Reporting]

Recently there were [some issues](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-winapps/bug-in-microsoft-security-essentials-lames-windows/7e105845-e4e7-4b0d-b7f8-485ba538e3b2) with the MSE engine, but they should be fixed already:

> This is due to an update that was shipped on April 15, 2014 that may have caused interrupted service for some customers using Microsoft security products. This was corrected via signature update, which automatically resolved the issue, and customers who have deployed the most recent signatures do not need to take any action.
>
> <sub>Source: [Antimalware Engine 1.1.10502.0 was released to customers on 17 April 2014](http://blogs.technet.com/b/enginenotifications/archive/2014/04/17/antimalware-engine-1-1-10502-0-was-released-to-customers-on-17-april-2014.aspx)</sub>

Basically you need to make sure MSE is up-to-date.

Comment: Also, to add: OP should update the Windows XP to Windows 7 or 8 depending on how good the hardware is.